# React/ Shopify: How to iterate over a prop with [{}] (Choice List Component)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, loops, shopify

I'm trying to have the title of my products be the choices of my Choice List. In the Shopify documentation its supposed to be like this

```
<ChoiceList
      title="Company name"
      choices={[
        {label: 'Hidden', value: 'hidden'},
        {label: 'Optional', value: 'optional'},
        {label: 'Required', value: 'required'},
      ]}
      selected={selected}
      onChange={handleChange}
    />
```

My code is like this

```
<ChoiceList
                choices={
                  [
                    data.forEach((element) => (
                      { label: `${element.title}` }
                    ))
                  ]
                }
                selected={selectedExport}
                onChange={handleSelectedExport}
              />
```

But this code does not seem to work. How should I change my code?

Answer (score 1):

You should be using `map` instead of `forEach` since you want to create a new array (`forEach` returns undefined). Also, you don't need to wrap it in brackets, as it's already an array:

```
<ChoiceList
  choices={data.map((element) => ({ label: `${element.title}` }))}
  selected={selectedExport}
  onChange={handleSelectedExport}
/>;
```

---

Side note: if `element.title` is already a string, you should just use `{ label: element.title }` or if you're feelin' fancy, destructure and use shorthand initialization:

```js
choices={data.map(({ title: label }) => ({ label }))}
```

If it is *not* a string, consider using `element.title.toString()` or another explicit method of converting it to a string.

Comment: I guess that `element.title` is already a string. `title` is not a property of any objects in the input array btw